# Having Problems with AzureChatOpenAI()

Tags: python, azure, openai-api, langchain, azure-openai

people. I'm trying to use the AzureChatOpenAI(), but even if I put the right parameters, it doesn't work. Here it is:

```
from langchain_core.messages import HumanMessage
from langchain_openai import AzureChatOpenAI
import os

os.environ['AZURE_OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT_NAME'] = "..."
os.environ["AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "..."
os.environ["AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT"] = "https://xxx.openai.azure.com/"
os.environ["AZURE_OPENAI_API_VERSION"] = "2024-02-15-preview"

model = AzureChatOpenAI(
            temperature=0,
            deployment_name=os.environ["AZURE_OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT_NAME"],
            azure_endpoint="AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT",
            api_version=os.environ["AZURE_OPENAI_API_VERSION"],
            openai_api_key=os.environ["AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY"],
            streaming=True,
)
```

And the error:

```
ValidationError: 1 validation error for AzureChatOpenAI
__root__
  As of openai>=1.0.0, Azure endpoints should be specified via the `azure_endpoint` param not `openai_api_base` (or alias `base_url`). (type=value_error)
```

Does someone had this same error? Do you know how to fix this?

Even if I put `azure_endpoint` until `openai_api_base`, it gives me the same ValidationError. I tried a lot of things but nothing worked at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem with initializing AzureChatOpenAI()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77548802/problem-with-initializing-azurechatopenai)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have configured the `OPENAI_API_BASE` environment variable.  It's value will be [automatically taken for `openai_api_base`](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/0ae39ab30ed27072aea938feb65efef74ef4fa4d/libs/partners/openai/langchain_openai/chat_models/azure.py#L122-L123). And that's what the error message(marked in bold) trying to say.

```
Azure endpoints should be specified via the `azure_endpoint` 
param not `openai_api_base` (or alias `base_url`). (type=value_error)
```

Either delete this enviorment variable(`OPENAI_API_BASE`) or add

```
del os.environ["OPENAI_API_BASE"]
```

just before creating `AzureChatOpenAI` instance.